# How to hide the digital time on watchOS 10?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos, iphone-privateapi

Before watchOS 10, I can hide the digital time on the status bar by this:

```
let app = Dynamic.PUICApplication.sharedPUICApplication()

app._setStatusBarTimeHidden(true, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

But this private API is no longer take effect on watchOS 10+. Does there any other API to hide the time?